# exception while sending mail through java code in netbeans while not in eclipse

Tags: java

using below code i can send mail through eclipse but using same code in netbeans gives exception as below.

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class SendMailSSL {  
 public static void main(String[] args) {  

     String to="shahjoy**@gmail.com";//change accordingly  
        final String user="shahjoy***@gmail.com"; //change accordingly  
        final String password="***";//change accordingly  

        //1) get the session object     
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); // for gmail use smtp.gmail.com
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
            protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
                return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
            }  
        });  

        //2) compose message     
        try{  
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
            message.setSubject("Message Alert");  

            //3) create MimeBodyPart object and set your message text     
            BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();  
            messageBodyPart1.setText("This is message body");  

            //4) create new MimeBodyPart object and set DataHandler object to this object      
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();  

         //  String filename = "SendMailSSL.txt";//change accordingly  
           // DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);  
           // messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));  
            //messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);  


            //5) create Multipart object and add MimeBodyPart objects to this object      
       Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();  
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);  
            //multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);  

         //  6) set the multipart object to the message object  
           message.setContent(multipart );  

            //) send message  
            Transport.send(message);  

            System.out.println("message sent....");  
        }catch (MessagingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}  }
```

Exception in netbeans:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at sendmailssl.SendMailSSL.send(SendMailSSL.java:61)
    at sendmailssl.SendMailSSL.main(SendMailSSL.java:73)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1439)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:878)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:814)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:507)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1421)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Have you tried port 587? have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Comment: i tried port 587.....but same exception

Comment: also tried this link...for certi "http://dwteam.in/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/"

Comment: The link is not valid

Comment: not valid means its not opening or it contain invalid or false data?

Comment: also tried this link...for certi "dwteam.in/…;  that link you posted is not valid

Comment: The link contains a double quote at the end, remove it and it works or click here http://dwteam.in/unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Answer (score 0):

A certificate seems to be missing in the classpath. Please check - perhaps Netbeans is using a different version of JDK/JRE than eclipse?

Comment: Cannot create J2SE platform for 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7'. Default platform will be used instead. default is also 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7'..

Comment: So the same JRE 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7' is being used by Netbeans and eclipse?